# Single reference to classical results in analysis.

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am writing an expository work. And I need classical references (books or articles) that simultaneously proof the three classical results below. Any suggestion?

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $(\mathbb{X},d_\mathbb{X})$ and $(\mathbb{Y},d_\mathbb{Y})$ be two metric spaces, and let $f:\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{Y}$ be continuous. If $\mathbb{X}$ is compact, then $f$ is 
>   uniformly continuous.

$\quad$

> **Theorem.** Let $(\mathbb{X},d_{\mathbb{X}})$ be a compact metric space and let $f:\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ be  continuous. Then $f$ has both a minimum and a maximum on $\mathbb{X}$.

$\quad$
Let $\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}$ be two topological spaces.
For a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{X}$ we denote by $\mathop{\mathrm{int}}(D)$, $\partial D$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{ext}}(D)=X\backslash (D\cup \partial D)=\mathop{\mathrm{int}}(X\backslash D)$ its interior, boundary and exterior respectively.
A function $f:\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{Y}$ is said to be continuous with
respect to $D\subseteq \mathbb{Y}$ if $f^{-1}(D)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{X}$.
$\quad$

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a connected topological space and let $\mathbb{Y}$ be a
>   topological space. Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{Y}$.
>   If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous with respect to both $\mathop{\mathrm{int}}(D)$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{ext}}(D)$, and if there are $a,b\in \mathbb{X}$ such
>   that $f(a)\in D$ and $f(b)\notin D$, then there exists $x\in\mathbb{ X}$ such
>   that $f(x)\in \partial D$.
>   In particular this is true if $f$ is continuous.

When $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Y} $ this result is sometimes known *customs theorem*.

Comment: What do you means by classical references?

Comment: @sinbadh,  books or articles.

Comment: I don't understand the third statement ; is $D$ a subset of $X$ or of $Y$ ?

Comment: The best book that i've read on in spanish about metric spaces is "Topología de Espacios Métricos" (Topology in Metric Spaces), by Ignacio Iribarren. That book has the three results that you want. So, at least in spanish, it is a classical reference

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck $D\subset \mathbb{Y}$.

Comment: Two references that should more than adequately cover not only what you asked about, but also most anything else that is likely to come up: Albert Wilansky's [**Topology for Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486469034) and Karl R. Stromberg's [**An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis**](http://bookstore.ams.org/CHEL-376-H).

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is $X$, what does it mean to say that it is continuous on $\operatorname{int} D$, which is a subset of $Y$?

Comment: @David, I repaired the question.

Comment: The last statement is false. Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of the set $(0,1)$. Then according to your definition, $f$ is continuous with respect to $D = (1/2, 3/2)$, and $f$ takes values both inside and outside $D$. However, $f$ never takes values in $\partial D$.

Comment: @David, now believe that there are no problems in the theorem. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The statement of the theorem now seems correct. I haven't seen it before, but it seems to me to be a trivial consequence of the definition of connectedness.